# How to use the django-filer file selector in a rich text editor?

Tags: django

Django filer is a great remote image file resource manager. I want to modify all projects to django filer to manage server image resources, but I don't know how to choose to use the django filer file selector from a rich text editor?

After consulting a lot of materials, I couldn't find a case where a rich text editor can perfectly integrate with django filer. Is it possible that the django filer file selector cannot be used in conjunction with a rich text editor?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you are asking about the django-filter library. Django-filter works with data in the ORM.
He needs a model.
The logic would be, create a table in the database that contains a field for loading image files. Create the filter.py . Use filters to find related files in the table. For me it is not possible to connect django-filter to a rich text box. You have to choose another path, JS in the DOM awaits you a lot I think.

in the link if you are interested in learning more about the topic, you will find a collection of tutorials with Django-Filter

[Django-filter Tutorial list](https://www.managepy.it/pages/second)

Comment: The question above by @hua-wang is refering to "django-filer" library and NOT "django-filter" library. Notice filer and not filter.